Why does ConcurrentModificationException occur without explicit concurrent modifications?
I’m encountering a ConcurrentModificationException when fetching a Question entity using Spring Data JPA.
Below is a simplified version of entity:
@Data
public class Question {
  //@ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

  //@ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

public class User {
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    private List<Question> questions;
}

public class Comment {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Question question;
}

The exception occurs during this repository invoke:
Question question = questionRepository.findById(id)
    .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);


I understand that ConcurrentModificationException in Java occurs when a collection is structurally modified while being iterated, as per the Oracle Java API documentation.

What did I try:

The exception disappears if I exclude both user and comments fields from the toString() method or remove @ToString entirely.

It seems related to how toString() interacts with relationships or lazy-loading during debugging or logging.

Checked my code for explicit concurrent modifications but found none.


My Question is:
Why does this exception occur even without explicit concurrent modifications, and how can I resolve it or did this problem come from Entity design?
Should I ignore this issue if it only happens in the debugger or logger?

is this lombok's @ToString?

Don't use @Data with JPA. It generates a wrong equals and hashCode for JPA and the toString is dangerous (it uses all fields which can lead to recursion with bi-direction relations). I've written a blog about this years ago (https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/)

Lombok maintainer here: The key question: What does your object represent? The only way JPA is ever going to work right, is: "a row in the database and that row represents a Question. This object does not; it merely represents a row". We can make lombok work properly then. But JPA maintainers appear unwilling to state this and we don't really feel like we should go explicitly against the semantic ideas of JPA's maintainers. We don't use JPA ourselves; if only someone would clarify precisely how equality is supposed to be written, we can add something like @JpaEquals.

@muralik yes, it's. But this problem thrown even when I implement a custom toString method

For example, if the answer is 'it reps the row' then equality should be defined solely on the primary key columns and nothing else, and in addition, 2 objects that have the same value for every field, and the primary key is unset (e.g. null) aren't equal to each other. Because if you save() both, you get 2 rows. And that's the semantic definition we'd be adhering to: a.equals(b) means: These 2 objects represent the same row.

BTW the Concurrent part of the exceptions name can be misleading, it can also happen in one single thread - from the same link you posted: "Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception."

@M.Deinum Hibernate don't use equals for that specific reason.

afaik it does and if you don't have a proper equals (solely on the id/business id etc.) things break. Especially when used in a collection or trying to re-attach objects to the session. Things will break, so yes in my experience hibernate does use the equals etc. (next to that I suspect vlad knows what he is talking about and same for the others of JPA Buddy).

@M.Deinum good blog, thanks. I'll try

@rzwitserloot so the advice is that I should implement custom equals hashCode and just rely on the primary key? does this violate any rules in OOP or potentially cause any problems in the future? Can you provide some good resource to study?

@user85421 I know it, however checked my code for explicit concurrent modifications but found none.

BTW most Exceptions include a Stack Trace - important information to help finding where the problem may be

@user85421 thank you, I will try it

@trongtoannguyen Yes. And of course that violates rules. DBs fundamentally do not adhere to the rules, so any attempt to equate java objects to db rows will run into semantic inconsistencies. Pull at this thread long enough and you end up at: Do not use JPA/Hibernate ever; use JOOQ/JDBI instead. Which is perhaps a bit drastic. Programming in a way that you adhere to every rule tends to lead to extremes like that. The usual fix is to treat 'rules' as guidelines (i.e. bend them or even break them when convenient).

@rzwitserloot there is so much good advice in this article. I appreciate it

The concurrent modification is (I suspect) due to one of the generated methods. Because it will iterate over the collection, call toString on those objects. Which will result in triggering a query to load the actual entity, modifying the collection while you are already iterating. Hence the collection has changed, leading to a concurrent modification exception when it continues with the next element in the collection. It happens due to a side effect of lazy loading basically.
